# I can't page permalink edit option in Wordpress page edit

Tags: wordpress

Thank you for your time.
I'm wordpress beginner and I have wordpress project and I created page.
I want to change page url but I can't see that option.

[Here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dfqG.png)

I tried clicking on the title, but it didn't appear.
Also, I installed elementor plugin but I can't see that option still

Answer (score 1):

Double-click to edit the URL and change the URL of your page.

OR

To change the permalink structure for all WordPress posts, go to the Admin Dashboard, click on "Settings," choose "Permalinks," select your desired structure, and save the changes.